# zshログイン時の終了ステータスが常に1になる

Tags: zsh

まずzshに限った問題ではないかもしれませんが、当方ではそれを判断しかねるためzshということで話をさせていただきます。

コマンドが成功したか失敗したか表示させたいと思ったのですが、通常時は問題なく終了ステータスを返すもののログイン時に終了ステータスが0になりません。
[image]

この様な仕様なのかと思いましたが他の方のログインを確認しても終了ステータスは問題なく0になっているようです
http://shutosg.hatenadiary.com/entry/2016/02/17/235545

.zshrcや.zshenv、zprofileを空にした状態でも変わりませんし、source ~/.zshrcなどを行っても終了ステータスは0が返ってきます。

ファイル以外の場所で何かしら問題があるのでしょうか？そしてそれはどうやって調べたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 問題はログイン時だけですか？  ログインシェルから実行したzshでも同じですか？

Comment: @mjy
ありがとうございます。
ログインシェルもzshですが、zsh上でzshを実行すると終了ステータスは0、つまり、成功します。

Comment: ターミナルのタブを増やすと、失敗します。

Comment: でしたら、`/etc/zprofile`、`~/.zprofile`、`/etc/zlogin`、`~/.zlogin`があやしいですね。ホームディレクトリ以下は空にしても駄目という事なので、`/etc/`以下の内容をチェックしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 私の環境では`/etc/`以下ではなく`/etc/zsh/`以下でした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

多くのシェルは、`-l`オプションを付けて起動するとログインシェルとして振る舞うので、

```
zsh -l -x
```

として実行すれば、ログイン時の挙動がある程度トレース出来ます。

シェル起動直後の`$?`は、シェルの起動中に最後に実行されたコマンドの戻り値になっているようです。
私の環境では、`~/.zlogin`があれば、それが最後に読み込まれ、無ければ`~/.zcompdump`を読み込んだ後に実行されている`compinit`というコマンドが、対話に入る直前のコマンドとなるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
たしかに、
'zsh -l -x'
を実行した結果、
最終的に~/.zloginにて、以前rbenvに変更したため既に削除したrvmをロードしておりエラーになっていたようです。
何故か~/.zloginについては今まで全く目に入りませんでした。

これからは、注意深くすべてのファイルを監視すると共に、オプションについても調べていきます。
適切なご指導を頂き大変に感謝しております。